#  Web service gives 401 error on https

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web-services

I am using a web service with jQuery. My web service works fine on http:// but it gives me a 401 (unauthorized) error when running on https://.

Please advise me on what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any bindings for HTTPS? Do you have a sever certificate installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed sever certificate for https.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but I had a similiar problem and because the IIS web server was set up to not use anonymous authentication, I had to add the following line to my web service call

```
myProxy.Credentials= System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```